# How to determine user DN after authentication against an Active Directory?

Tags: c#, authentication, activedirectorymembership

I'm using DirectoryServices to authenticate a user against an ADLDS (the lighteweight Active Directory). After I pass authentication. How can I determine the DN or SID of the currently logged in user?

```
using (DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(<a>LDAP://XYZ:389</a>,
userName.ToString(),
password.ToString(),
AuthenticationTypes.Secure))
{
try
{
// Bind to the native object to force authentication to happen
Object native = entry.NativeObject;
MessageBox.Show("User authenticated!");
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
throw new Exception("User not authenticated: " + ex.Message);
}
...
```

Thanks

#### Update:

I get an exception at

```
src = search.FindAll() 
There is no such object on the server.
```

I realized the user logging in has a class type "foreignSecurityPrincipal" in the Active Directory lightweight so I figured perhaps I can just modify your filter to be:

```
search.Filter = "(&(objectclass=foreignSecurityPrincipal)" + "(sAMAccountName=" + userName + "))";
```

But that gave me the same exception. Any idea what I am missing?

Answer (score 3):

To my knowledge you will have to do an LDAP Search for the user and get the **distinguishedName** property from AD.  See below:

```
// you can use any root DN here that you want provided your credentials
// have search rights
DirectoryEntry searchEntry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://XYZ:389");

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher(searchEntry);
search.Filter = "(&(objectclass=user)(objectCategory=person)" +
  "(sAMAccountName=" + userName + "))";    

if (search != null)
{
  search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("sAMAccountName");
  search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("cn");
  search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("distinguishedName");

  log.Info("Searching for attributes");

  // find firest result
  SearchResult searchResult = null;
  using (SearchResultCollection src = search .FindAll())
  {
 if (src.Count > 0)
   searchResult = src[0];
  }

  if (searchResult != null)
  {
    // Get DN here
    string DN = searchResult.Properties["distinguishedName"][0].ToString();
  }
```

Comment: mjmarsh Thanks ~ but I get an exception at src = search.FindAll()

There is no such object on the server.

------

I realized the user logging in has a class type "foreignSecurityPrincipal" in the Active Directory lightweight so I figured perhaps I can just modify your filter to be:
search.Filter = "(&(objectclass=foreignSecurityPrincipal)" + "(sAMAccountName=" + userName + "))";

But that gave me the same exception. Any idea what I am missing? I feel like your code is getting me very close to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

When I add a new user manually in the active directory, the 'distinguished Name' cannot be define manually but the convention seems to be the first name + ' ' + the last name. In this case, why not trying to get the 'distinguished name' following this pattern. I also found that if I just specified a first name to create a non-human user, the 'distinguihed name' is the equal to the first name without space after.

I follow this pattern in my application and it works and it's much simple than trying to create custom query to search user.